# Can't get div overflow to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm hoping someone can help me with an issue I'm running into. I'm trying to set up a series of photos. That have this CSS/HTML property:

http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/7GvV2/embedded/result%2chtml%2ccss/

```
    /*
 * Housekeeping
 */
body {
    font: normal 16px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 480px;
}

/*
 * Caption component
 */
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Only the -webkit- prefix is required these days */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.caption__media {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.caption__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -webkit-calc(-100% - 10px) );
            transform: translateY( calc(-100% - 10px) );

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}
```

I actually got the code from this site.

But there will be upwards of 30 photos, so I was hoping to put them inside a scrolling box/area about 400h x 700w px. When I add the scrolling box, either by HTML, or CSS the results are the same. There is a box, with no scrolling. And all photo's have been shrunken down to fit inside of the box.

Can anyone PLEASE help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try removing the `overflow: hidden` from `.caption`?

Comment: i think you should use `<iframe>`

Comment: Can you give me an idea or example of how to do that?

Comment: In my opinion <iframe> it's just a bad practice. It should be used only when there is no other option

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is removed the CSS for the `.container` element, in case you want to keep that for a different purpose, and added a `.scroller` element as a wrapper around the images (within the `.container`). If you don't have another use for the `.container`, you can replace `.scroller` in the CSS with `.container`, and remove the `.container` I added to the HTML. A little wordy, so if you need an easier explanation let me know.

So the HTML changes in that there's a new `<div>` with class `scroller` surrounding the `<article>` elements.

The CSS adds the .scroller class, and another rule just to space the images apart a little bit:

```
.scroller{
    margin:0px auto;
    height:400px;
    max-height:400px;
    width:700px;
    max-width:700px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.scroller article:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/435rx66s/

Comment: Wow, this is pretty damn nice! Thank you so much for this. I really appreciate it.
I'll reply when I implement it.

Comment: Is there any way to get the images to sit side by side, and have it scroll horizontally?
When I tried to use this code the images I am using blew up in size. How do I control that? 

Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

What is this scroll box / area?

You've given us this code that you referenced in your implementation, but where is your implementation for us to reference?

The given code works well if you are creating more articles within that container. Give the container a fixed height and set overflow to auto and there should be no problem with getting this content to sit within a scrolling box.

https://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/7GvV2/

```
.container {
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 480px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're open to a bit of jquery, there's quite a simple solution.

a short jquery function

```
$("#container > article:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('#container > article:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#container');
}, 3000);
```

will show your articles in turn.

```js
$("#container > article:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('#container > article:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#container');
}, 3000);
```

```css
/*
 * Housekeeping
 */
body {
    font: normal 16px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 480px;
    max-height:240px;
   overflow:hidden;
}



/*
 * Caption component
 */
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Only the -webkit- prefix is required these days */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.caption__media {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.caption__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -webkit-calc(-100% - 10px) );
            transform: translateY( calc(-100% - 10px) );

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

article{max-width:480px; max-height:240px; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

    <article class="caption">
        <img class="caption__media" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6088/6128773012_bd09c0bb4e_z_d.jpg" />
        <div class="caption__overlay">
            <h1 class="caption__overlay__title">Alaska</h1>
            <p class="caption__overlay__content">
                Alaska is a U.S. state situated in the northwest extremity of the North American continent. Bordering the state is Canada to the east, the Arctic Ocean to the north, and the Pacific Ocean to the west and south, with Russia (specifically, Siberia) further west across the Bering Strait.
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>

        <article class="caption">
        <img class="caption__media" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6088/6128773012_bd09c0bb4e_z_d.jpg" />
        <div class="caption__overlay">
            <h1 class="caption__overlay__title">Michigan</h1>
            <p class="caption__overlay__content">
               Some dummy text for testing
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>

    </div>
  

</div>
```

Comment: actually you don't need the overflow:hidden;on the article css, just the container